# Natural Language Calculator Conversion Issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, calculator

I'm working on a small nlp project, which will basically take natural language and work with it. The aspect that I am dealing with is taking a fairly basic sentence, "I have 32 apples, 8 oranges, and 10 bananas." What I want to do with it, is search the string for integers, convert them to an array, and sum it. Here is what I currently have:

```
import re
import numpy as np

myString = 'i have 32 apples, 8 oranges, and 10 bananas.'

def evaluation (foo):
    numsineval = re.findall(r'\d+', foo)
    myarray =  np.asarray(numsineval)
    yay = np.cumsum(myarray)
    print(yay)
evaluation(myString)
```

I have been banging my head against this wall for a couple days and would really love some help. Thanks! I have found an NLP calculator that other people have written, but am unable to decipher their code in such a way as to make it useful. If someone could help me out, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Okay so if I understood you right (you should mention what exactly doesnt work the way you want it),change:

numsineval = list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', foo))); and

yay = sum(myarray)

Comment: That worked. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without `numpy`:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'i have 32 apples, 8 oranges, and 10 bananas.'
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', s)
['32', '8', '10']
>>> sum(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', s)))
50
```

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of Banana, this code is what works:

```
myString = 'i have 32 apples, 8 oranges, and 10 bananas.'

def evaluation (foo):
    numsineval = list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', foo)))
    myarray =  np.asarray(numsineval)
    yay = sum(myarray)
    print(yay)
evaluation(myString)
```

Thanks!